# Acessing UserRoles table in aspnet identity via linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

So i can access the User table, but i need to do a further query within my linq statement to check to see if they have been added into a particular user role

```
var managers = (from a in db.Users 
                        join b in db.**UserRoles** on a.Id equals b.Id
                        where a.IsManager == true select a).ToList();
```

I know you can access it via the html using User.IsInRole, but i really need to access it via my DB call

any help would be great

Comment: I have a similar problem using but want to return all roles for the logged in user.  Using Database First I can see AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles but not the AspNetUserRoles.  AspNetUserRoles, in my context, is the relationship join and does not display as an actual table.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you are using asp.net identity with code-first approach? you can access the users or Roles tables individually (db.Users/db.Roles). If you want to access roles for a user you could do db.Users.Roles. However, this would only return id's for your roles (there are no navigationproperty from here..)

To check for users in role by role-name, you could join user.Roles with db.Roles, and check the role name from db.Roles. Something like this:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var user1 = new ApplicationUser { Email = "user1@test.com", UserName = "User #1"};
    var user2 = new ApplicationUser { Email = "user2@test.com", UserName = "User #2 - No Roles" };
    var role1 = new IdentityRole("SomeRole");
    db.Users.Add(user1);
    db.Users.Add(user2);
    db.Roles.Add(role1);
    db.SaveChanges();
    user1.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole { RoleId = role1.Id });
    db.SaveChanges();
    var usersInRole = db.Users.Where(u =>
        u.Roles.Join(db.Roles, usrRole => usrRole.RoleId,
        role => role.Id, (usrRole, role) => role).Any(r => r.Name.Equals("SomeRole"))).ToList();}
```

Alternatively you could first fetch the Role and then check

```
var usersinRole = db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId.Equals(someRoleId)));
```

Comment: I agree with @Jerome2606.  The alternative LINQ solved my problem but I'm not sure how to interpret what I'm reading.  Also, mine ended up being in reverse so it became: `var data = context.AspNetRoles.Where(r => r.AspNetUsers.Any(u => u.UserName.Equals(username))).ToList();`  This let me get all the roles for the passed in `username`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of you are using you should have some tables like this:

[image]

You will need to join to the users in roles table and the roles table.

Comment: I'm using version 2, and have the table AspNetUserRoles but it is not available for me to access out of the box

Comment: How are your other models and database connected?

Comment: I don't fully understand what your asking me sorry. I'm using entity framework and using a DBContext(if that's what you meant?)

Comment: Sort of. If you are doing DB first and have an .edmx file for instance, you need to: 1) open the .edmx file 2) right click in the editor 3) select `Update Model from Database...` 4) connect the the database and select the tables to add.